# How should I loop through asynchronous functions that rely on the previous loop's value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

The synchronous version (simplified for readability) of what I'm trying to do in node.js:

```
var value = null;
var allValues = [];
do{
  value = getValue(value); //load the next value
  if(value) allValues.push(value);
}while(value);
console.log("Got all values:",allValues);
```

The goal being to iterate through all values, however unless I pass in the current value the getValue function will simply return the first value (causing an infinite loop).

In node.js the getValue() function is asynchronous, and I want it to be asynchronous, however if I do this:

```
var allValues = [];
function iterateGetValue(value){
    if(value){
        allValues.push(value);
        getValue(value,iterateGetValue);
    }else console.log("Got all values:",allValues);
}
getValue(null,iterateGetValue);
```

I'm concerned that N iterations down (getValue could fire thousands of times before hitting the end) I'll hit a stack limit problem (am I incorrect?). I've looked into Promises and other async tricks but all of them appear to me to continue to push the stack (am I incorrect?).

Are my stack limit assumptions incorrect, or is there some obvious way to do this that I'm missing?

Also, I can't busy-wait to turn the async getValue into a synchronous getValue, that defeats the whole purpose of using asynchronous.

Comment: Recursively calling getValue is the correct way to do what you want, and you shouldn't run into stack issues, unless you would also run into memory issues in the completely iterative version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'll hit a stack limit

No, you won't. If they're really asynchronous, then the next call to `iteratGetValue` will be in a new stack frame - originating in the top-level execution context of the async callback handler. It's the same for Promises - [some of which](http://promisesaplus.com/) are even *required* to be asynchronous.